# onActivityResult is not calling using camera activity

Tags: android-camera-intent

```
Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

After taking photo can't call onActivityResult

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
 {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        //CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getContext(), photo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was tested Samsung Galaxy S4 with lower android version. I took the photo. But startActivityForResult(); can't call onActivityResult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fixed using this line

> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

into the **AndroidManifest** file with related activity.